# how to get javascript code as a responce and set in div from ajax page?

Tags: php

I want to get Facebook comments box, which I am getting from AJAX page in response. But when the data is coming from ajax, I am alerting it. It is showing in alert box, but when I am trying to set it in my div, it's not setting properly.

Here is my piece of code in which I want to set in div to get from the AJAX page.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
     <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=23423424242" data-width="470"></div>
```

Why is it not setting in the div?

Answer (score 0):

Assign ajax response to `div` like this

```
$('#your_div').html(response);
```

Comment: iam assigning but data is not setting in div

Comment: no problem dear... but when we getting script tag in response... does it conflicting some time with other ajax functions ?